# #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String> for jwt encoding environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt

I am receiving a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String` for my encode_token method using a "jwt_secret" environment.

I have made sure that my

Here is my ApplicationController. The encode_token is the problem method and I believe this has to do with my jwt_secret env not being recognized by the my front-end client, which is a React app that sends a fetch request to the Rails database:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authorized, except: [:encode_token, :decoded_token, :logged_in?]

  def encode_token(payload)
    JWT.encode(payload, ENV["jwt_secret"])
  end

  def auth_header
    request.headers['Authorization']
  end

  def decoded_token
    if auth_header()
      token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
      begin
        JWT.decode(token, ENV["jwt_secret"], true, algorithm: 'HS256')
      rescue JWT::DecodeError
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  def current_user
    if decoded_token()
      user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id']
      @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def authorized
    render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

And my users controller:

```rb
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :find_user, only: [:show]
  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:index, :create]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @token = encode_token(user_id: @user.id)
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), jwt: @token }, status: :created
    else
      render json: { error: 'failed to create user' }, status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: @user
  end

end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
end
```

Comment: `ENV["jwt_secret"]` is not defined. its returning `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have issue with your configuration of ENV["jwt_secret"]. Let us first try it by hard coding values replace  `JWT.encode(payload, ENV["jwt_secret"])` with following line

```
JWT.encode(payload, "your_secret_key_anything_text")
```

Now try, if it works, that mean you have issue in your configuration file and it is not getting your secret key. Now let us resolve issue. Let us try some solution. If you have `.env` already setup and working with configurations, than just add following line

```
JWT_SECRET='yoursecretkey'
```

1. add following gem in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

No use `bundle install` to install this Gem, You have to specify ENV["jwt_secret"] in your .env file.

```
JWT_SECRET='yoursecretkey'
```

in Rails 5.2 you can use `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` to add this variable in secrets too, which whole process is little bit complicated to suggest to check documentation.